# Implicit conversion from float to int loses precision when trying to access array

Tags: php

So the error message here is straightforward but I cannot figure out why it is happening. Just upgraded to PHP 8 and trying to work through fixing deprecations.

I have `$object` which looks like this (all string keys):

```
Array
(
    [a] => ABC
    [b] => 599.97
    [c] => 0.00
    [d] => 50
    [e] => Test
)
```

I have `$field` and when I do `var_dump($field)` I get `float(1.05)`

In my code the following is happening: I want to check if `$field` is a valid key of `$object`. If it is, I want to use the accessed value via the key, if not, I want to use `$field` as the value instead.

So I have the following code:

`$a = $object[$field] ?? $field;`

However it is this EXACT line of code that is triggering the following warning:

`DEPRECATED | PID: 6978 | CODE: 8192 | MESSAGE: Implicit conversion from float 1.05 to int loses precision`

I thought maybe it has something to do with the null coalescence but this code triggers the same warning too:

`$a = $object[$field];`

Note that `$a` here is just a random stand-in unused variable that I didn't type hint or declare anywhere else, and when I use this dummy variable, the warning still occurs.

Why is this happening? How is there an implicit conversion to `int` happening here? It's driving me crazy trying to fix this.

Comment: The only thing I can guess is that since 1.05 is a float and not a string, and I don't think floats are valid array keys, it's trying to convert 1.05 to check for `$object[1]` -- See https://php.watch/versions/8.1/deprecate-implicit-conversion-incompatible-float-string

Comment: Yes, this was exactly it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (emphasis mine)-

> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> ...
>
> **Floats are also cast to ints, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8.**
>
> ...

Comment: Aha this was the exact issue! I hadn't considered this at all, and it's unfortunate that I need to take a step back in conciseness and add an extra check to address this, but I understand the logic behind the change. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In PHP array's key could be int or string. Every other type need to be converted to one of these.

When you do `$object[1.05]` it internally converts this value to int, so it executes `$object[1]`, but this behaviour can be misleading, so since PHP 8.1 you get warning.